# Android, random from external json

Tags: android, json, random

I am working on an android app. I want the app to select randomly a name from json. 
Here is the json :

```html
{
"user": [
{
"id": "001",
"name": "Raj Amal",
"email": "raj.amalw@gmail.com"
},
{
"id": "002",
"name": "Raj",
"email": "amalw@gmail.com"
}
]
}
```

And here is my android code :

```js
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 TextView uid;
 TextView name1;
 TextView email1;
 Button Btngetdata;
 
 //URL to get JSON Array
 private static String url = "http://weblink/json/index.php";
 
 //JSON Node Names 
 private static final String TAG_USER = "user";
 private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
 private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
 private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
 
 JSONArray user = null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
           new JSONParse().execute();

    
   }
  });
        
        
    }


    
    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
      private ProgressDialog pDialog;
     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
             uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
    name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
    email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            
     }
     
     @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
      JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

      // Getting JSON from URL
      JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
      return json;
     }
      @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
       pDialog.dismiss();
       try {
        // Getting JSON Array
        user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
        JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);
        
        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
        
        
        //Set JSON Data in TextView
        uid.setText(id);
        name1.setText(name);
        email1.setText(email);

       
      } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

       
      }
    }`
```

I would that when I presse the button a random name shows and loops.

Please help 
Thank you

Comment: create a list of names and use a random number to select name from list

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is what I am trying to do
I need to select a random id and show the name with the same id.
But I really don't know how to 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change `JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);` by this line ->

```
JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(new Random().nextInt(user.length()));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to generate Random number from your array
first try this to add items in temp Arraylist. i am just only adding characters you need to replace name instead of characters

```
String json="{'abridged_cast':
[{'name':'JeffBridges','id':'162655890','characters':['JackPrescott']},  
{'name':'CharlesGrodin','id':'162662571','characters':['FredWilson']},  
{'name':'JessicaLange','id':'162653068','characters':['Dwan']},
{'name':'JohnRandolph','id':'162691889','characters':['Capt.Ross']},
{'name':'ReneAuberjonois','id':'162718328','characters':['Bagley']}]}";

JSONObject jsonResponse;
try {
     temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray movies = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("abridged_cast"); // add 
    //user here instead of abridged_cas
    for(int i=0;i<movies.length();i++){
        JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray characters = movie.getJSONArray("characters"); // replace 
        //name instead of characters
        for(int j=0;j<characters.length();j++){
            temp.add(characters.getString(j));
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Json: "+temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

here is you get names randomly using onclick or whatever you want.

```
Random randomizer = new Random();
String RandomName = temp.get(randomizer.nextInt(temp.size()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the JSON input. You can use java function int random = Random.nextInt(n). This returns a random int in range[0, n-1].

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray socialArray = response.getJSONArray(data);
      for (int i = 0; i < socialArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentJSON = socialArray.getJSONObject(i);
            names.add(currentJSON.getString("name");
      }
final int random = Random.nextInt(names.size() + 1); 
Toast.makeText(this, "Random Name: " + names.get(random), LENGTH.SHORT).show();
```